# Firebase OnValueChanged Notifications for Unity (Android&iOS)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, notifications

I have a chat app like WhatsApp in Unity. I want to send user notification when he received any Chat.

What I've tried yet...
I have `OnChildAdded` Listener but it only works when Scene is Running on Foreground.

Simple Notifications in Unity which only shows notifications after some time delay.

How can I Keep the Firebase OnChildAdded Services running in the background and show a notification to the user when any child is added to the Chats Node? (firebase - realtime)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Realtime Database will not continue to work in the background (in fact, once your Activity/game is not visible, Android and iOS may kill it to save battery life or free up memory for another app).

If you'd like to send a message to a user when your app is not running, [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging) would be the way to go.

There is a rough tutorial that may help [here](https://medium.com/@97preveenraj/firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-with-firebase-realtime-database-7388493cb869) - although it references the Android SDK rather than the Unity one.

I hope that helps!

--Patrick